# MongoDB высылает пустой массив после метода find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

когда я решил написать проект на node.js + mongoDB возникла проблема.
У меня есть документ в базе данных(один):

```
"monday":[""],
"tuesday":["russian","biology","literature","english","algebra","geometry"],
"wednesday":[""],
"thursday":[""],
"friday":[""],
"saturday":[""]
}
```

Есть схема mongoose:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var conn = mongoose.createConnection(
  "mydb/timetable",
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
);
const timetable = new mongoose.Schema({
  monday: [String],
  tuesday: [String],
  wednesday: [String],
  thursday: [String],
  friday: [String],
  saturday: [String],
});
module.exports = conn.model("Timetable", timetable);
```

И вот отрывок основного файла с роутами:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const Timetable = require("./models/timetable");
app.get("/timetable", async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const timetable = await Timetable.find({});
    res.json(timetable)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
```

Когда я делаю get запрос на /timetable получаю просто [], хотя как указано выше в бд хранится документ. Подозреваю, что проблема в схеме - запросы, где не возвращаются массивы отлично проходят без всяких проблем.

Comment: А этот вот документ - он в нужной коллекции лежит?

Comment: да, однозначно. Я проверял + на других запросах все тоже хорошо

Comment: Что-то не воспроизводится Ваша проблема. Взял код из вопроса, вручную создал в коллекции `timetables` приведенный документ, и в итоге `Timetable.find({})` его благополучно находит. Он у Вас точно в `timetables`, а не в `timetable`?

Comment: А, еще у Вас странная connection string, mongoose, вообще говоря, на такой формат ругается нехорошими словами.

Comment: 1. А почему коллекция называется timetables, а не timetable? Может быть моя проблема в этом

Comment: 2. Я используя MongoDB Atlas и просто не палю connection string

Comment: 1. Потому что так устроен mongoose. Он использует имена коллекций, соответствующие именам моделей во множественном числе. :)

Comment: спасибо вам большое) я просто новичок и два дня ковырялся с этим)